# How to sort the values in one column based on other column values?

Tags: awk, sed, sort, gawk

I want to sort the given tab separated data.

- first level is column #1 and is sorted in increasing order
- second level is column #2 is also sorted in increasing order, (but conditional); 
  **condition:** column #3 should be grouped by unique values but sort order in column #2, should also be preserved as much as possible (with smallest range being at top).
- column #3 isn't sorted at all, but should be grouped.

Input Data:

```
2    15881764  9         C|T
2    15881767  9         C|C
2    15881989  4         C|C
2    15882091  4         G|T
2    15882451  9         C|T
2    15882454  9         C|T
2    15882493  9         C|T
2    15882505  6         A|T
3    16882450  6         C|T
3    16882594  6         C|T
3    16882633  6         C|T
3    16882755  6         A|T
```

Expected output:

```
2    15881764  9         C|T
2    15881767  9         C|C
2    15882451  9         C|T
2    15882454  9         C|T
2    15882493  9         C|T
2    15881989  4         C|C
2    15882091  4         G|T
2    15882505  6         A|T
3    16882450  6         C|T
3    16882594  6         C|T
3    16882633  6         C|T
3    16882755  6         A|T
```

Any unix based utilities is fine, but sort and awk preferable, owing to readability.

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!"  Accepting an answer also indicates to _future_ readers that the answer actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sort -k1,1n -k3,3n -k2,2n file
```

Sort first by col 1 numerically.
If there is a tie, then by col 3 numerically.
If there is a tie, then by col 2 numerically.

Comment: I had explained my way of data sorting, but looks like the wording or the input wasn't enough to say what I intended.

Comment: The question has changed a little bit. Can you have a look at it?

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is solved if you do a `sort` on the third field, just `sort -n -k3` but for the best you could do

```
sort -t$'\t' -n -k3 -k2 -k1 file
```

If you look at the [`man` page of `sort`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) you would see the `-k` denotes the field in the each line default delimited by space that you want to sort on. The `-t` flag allows you to set the de-limiter which according to your last edit being a <kbd>Tab</kbd>  character.

Comment: a brief explanation please. Why k3 first?

Comment: Because you specify that all entries should be grouped by that field?

Comment: @everestial007: Hope my last edit was useful